# How to authenticate Oauth v1 and PHP

Tags: php, oauth

I am using this code to verify the account of users with twitter.

```
 $signature = ??????
 $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.digits.com/1.1/sdk/account.json');
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-length: 0',
            'Content-type: application/json',
            'Authorization: ' . 'OAuth oauth_nonce="39914766530163254991478493084", oauth_timestamp="1478493084", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_consumer_key="' . $consumerKey . '", oauth_token="' . $oauthToken . '", oauth_signature="'.$signature.'"',
        ));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        $result = curl_exec($curl);
        $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
        if ($info['http_code'] == 200) {
            $r = json_decode($result);
//            var_dump($r->phone_number);
//            die();
            if (strval($r->phone_number) == strval($phone)) {
                // phone is equal, validate the user
                curl_close($curl);
                return true;
            } else {
                // phone is not equal
                curl_close($curl);
                return false;
            }

        } else {
            // unable to auth the user
            curl_close($curl);
            return false;
        }
```

but I do not know what should I use instead of $signature. how can I generate $signature.

regards

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$url   = 'https://api.digits.com/1.1/sdk/account.json';
$consumerKey = 'test';
$consumerSecret = 'test';
$oAuth = new OAuth( $consumerKey, $consumerSecret );
echo $oAuth->generateSignature( 'GET', $url ); //EYCZrp4cBizLgXcSX5ex4pYKI8g= (or something like it)
```

**[php-oauth](http://php.net/manual/en/class.oauth.php)** need to be installed on your server https://www.php.net/manual/en/oauth.installation.php.